# If localStorage item is null, set item, otherwise return item in Observable?

Tags: angular, local-storage, observable

I'm working on an Angular 6 app where I want to store commonly-used, but rarely-changed object arrays in localStorage.  I have a service class that is used to retrieve these arrays from a web service.  The functions in the service return observables.  I want to check the localStorage to see if the array is already there.  If it isn't, then I want to get the array from the web service and set the localStorage item to the returned value.  If it is there already, just return what is stored.  I'm struggling with how to return an observable from all possible branches of that conditional.  Seems like something someone has already done, but I can't find any examples of this...

Here's my existing function for returning one of these arrays:

```js
getApprovalRoutes(): Observable < ApprovalRoute[] > {
  if (!localStorage.getItem("allRoutes")) {
    this.http.get < ApprovalRoute[] > (`${this.baseUrl}/Routes`).subscribe(ar => {
      localStorage.setItem("allRoutes", JSON.stringify(ar));
      return Observable.from(ar);
    });
  } else {
    return Observable.from(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allRoutes")));
  }
}
```

When I run this I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Thanks for the help!

Comment: For reasons having to do with this particular app, we need an observable returned here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.http.get < ApprovalRoute[] > (`${this.baseUrl}/Routes`).subscribe(ar => {
  localStorage.setItem("allRoutes", JSON.stringify(ar));
  return Observable.from(ar);
});
```

The above doesn't return an observable. You can't return a value in a subscriber to the caller of the function.

```
return Observable.from(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allRoutes")));
```

The above uses `from()` which converts an array of values into individually emitted values. This doesn't match the return type `Observable<ApprovalRoute[]>` which emits an array.

Based upon what I see in your example. I think maybe this is what you were trying to.

```
getApprovalRoutes(): Observable<ApprovalRoute[]> {
    return of(localStorage.getItem('allRoutes'))
        .pipe(
            switchMap(routes => {
                if (!routes) {
                    return this.http.get<ApprovalRoute[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/Routes`)
                        .pipe(tap(ar => localStorage.setItem('allRoutes', JSON.stringify(ar))));
                }
                return of(JSON.parse(routes));
            })
        );
}
```

You want to emit the values from localStorage, and if the value is empty switch to a HTTP request. Tab into the HTTP results and put that into storage.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I was going for.  Thank you!